# Problem with eso-pic image positioning

Tags: eso-pic

I have problem with eso -pic package and my MWE like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=1]{index}}} % Image background
\raggedleft
\vspace*{9cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Maple 18 Guide to Started\par % Book title
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge Hirwanto}\par % Author name
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

And the result like this :

[image: io]

But, I want the result like this :

[image: ioo]

How to solution it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you say `\put(0,0)` you are putting your picture in the lower left corner of the page.

I suggest you to use `\AtTextUpperLeft` and then adjust the values of `\put` to position your image. For example:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
     \AtTextUpperLeft{%
         \put(-30,-200){\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}}%
     }%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
     \AtTextUpperLeft{%
         \put(-30,-200){\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}}%
     }%
}
\raggedleft
\vspace*{9cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{25}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Maple 18 Guide to Started\par % Book title
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge Hirwanto}\par % Author name
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]